Создание кнопок в obsidian
Ранее пользовался marktext и встраивал кнопки ввиде html кода, но теперь перешел на obsidian. Есть ли какое-то расширение или встроенная функция позволяющая вставлять html код в obsidian, либо просто расширение для кнопок?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

В Obsidian

НЕТ

встроенной функции для вставки HTML-кода

Возможные варианты :

Obsidian поддерживает базовый HTML внутри Markdown.

К примеру этот код создаст кнопку, которая при нажатии покажет сообщение "Hello, world!".
<button onclick="alert('Hello, world!')">Click me</button>


Templater — плагин для создания шаблонов, который позволяет вставлять html.

Advanced Tables - также поддерживает использование html.


